# Transparency on Linked Groups in OpenGL

Tags: rendering, transparency, linked-data, opengl

I am attempting to render a scene in OpenGl with several linked groups which include objects with transparent textures. While the transparency appears in the original Blend file of each model by checking Display > Transparency in the Properties panel, this option is not available when linking groups.

Posts as recently as 2013 mentioned this might be addressed, but is a low priority. Is this now possible? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed it, this has not yet been fixed. I actually reported this as bug once and that's how I learned it's considered a "known limitation", not a bug. Viewport transparency on dupligroups just straight up isn't supported.

If you really need to see past an object in a dupligroup, the max draw type on the source object is still respected, so you can set this to wireframe or bounding box. (max draw type is located in the object > display panel too, right next to the transparency checkbox)

Comment: This is just for blocking animation, so adjusting the max draw type will work for now. Thanks for the quick response!